# C# I/O exception "This machine is disabled for file encryption.\r\n"

Tags: c#, .net, encryption-symmetric

I'm implementing a simple C# console application for Encrypt or Decrypt a given file. Here im using inbuilt methods of .net framework. please look at the following program that shows the class that is responsible for handle the Encrypt and decrypt operations.

```
class FileHandler
{
    string fileToHandle = null;//name of the file
    private Boolean isEncrypted = false;//yes or no
    public FileHandler(string fileToHandle)
    {
        this.fileToHandle = fileToHandle;
    }
    //encrypt the current file
    public void encrypt()
    {
        if (!isEncrypted)
        {
            try
            {
                File.Encrypt(fileToHandle);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }

    }
    //decrypt the current file
    public void decrypt()
    {
        if (isEncrypted)
        {
            try
            {
                File.Decrypt(fileToHandle);
            }
            catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when i'm trying to use the method encrypt() it ends with an I/O error which states the message "This machine is disabled for file encryption.\r\n". I'm using .net framework 4.5 in windows 7 enterprise edition. I have NTFS file system in my Hard drive.

Please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 3):

`File.Encrypt` does NTFS file encryption. If the filesystem is not NTFS or the user you are running under does not have rights to modify the NTFS settings (Edit: [Or NTFS File encryption is disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25562595/80274)) you won't be able to use the `File.Encrypt` functions.

Comment: here i have NTFS file system but it's not working :( why is that

Comment: If the file is NTFS then it is option 2 or 3, either file encryption is disabled or you don't have the rights to modify the file you are trying to encrypt. What is the filepath of the file? If it is `C:\Something.txt` only Administrators have rights to modify files on the root of a drive. See if your program works if you do "run as a administrator" when you start it.

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\EFS]
EfsConfiguration=0 (dword)
LastGoodEfsConfiguration=0 (dword)
```

Change dword value to 1 to disable and 0 to enable.

Comment: where can i find this location

Comment: @Sandaru that is a registry key. Do you know how to find a registry key?

Comment: @Sandaru: Have a look @ [Learn How to Use the Windows Registry Editor (Regedit) in One Easy Lesson by techsupportalert](http://www.techsupportalert.com/content/learn-how-use-windows-registry-editor-regedit-one-easy-lesson.htm)

Comment: @Sandaru: Yes, please. Reboot your machine.